# First Python Script - Web Scraper with results saved to MySQL DB

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on getting more experience with Python so I made a basic Web Scraper, that saves it to MySQL.

*The code is currently working*, but looking at it is very frustrating because it seems extremely redundant to me.

**Some fake html** - This does emulate the sites tree.

```
 <div class="tab_row">
  <h4>World</h4>
  <div class="discount_original_price">$1.99</div>
  <div class="discount_final_price">$1.99</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tab_row">
  <h4>World2</h4>
  <div class="discount_original_price">$2.99</div>
  <div class="discount_final_price">$2.99</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tab_row">
  <h4>World3</h4>
  <div class="discount_original_price">$3.99</div>
  <div class="discount_final_price">$3.99</div>
 </div>
 <div class="tab_row">
  <h4>World4</h4>
  <div class="discount_original_price">$4.99</div>
  <div class="discount_final_price">$3.99</div>
 </div>
```

**My Python Script**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
import dbconfig as cfg
origPage = 'http://localhost'
page = urllib2.urlopen(origPage)
import sys
import MySQLdb as mdb
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')

def pullGames():
 soup = BeautifulSoup (page, 'html.parser')
 #(page, 'html.parser')

 #Let's pull prices
 names = []
 pricing = []
 discounts = []
 discountPct = []
 #Push items to array for saving
 for name in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'tab_row'}):
  names.append(name.h4.text)
 for price in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'discount_original_price'}):
  pricing.append(price.text)
 for discount in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'discount_final_price'}):
  discounts.append(discount.text)
 for percent in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'discount_pct'}):
  discountPct.append(percent.text)


 con = mdb.connect(cfg.mysql['host'], cfg.mysql['user'], cfg.mysql['passwd'], cfg.mysql['db']);
 cur = con.cursor()
 con.set_character_set('utf8')
 cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
 cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
 cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')


 for i in range(len(names)):
  sql = 'INSERT INTO game_pricing(game_name, original_price, discount_price) \
         VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s")' % \
         (names[i],pricing[i],discounts[i])
 #print sql
  cur.execute(sql)      
  con.commit()

def checkDb():
 con = mdb.connect(cfg.mysql['host'], cfg.mysql['user'], cfg.mysql['passwd'], cfg.mysql['db']);
 cur = con.cursor()
 con.set_character_set('utf8')
 cur.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
 cur.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
 cur.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
 sql = 'SELECT game_name, original_price, discount_price FROM game_pricing'
 cur.execute(sql)
 results = cur.fetchall()
 for row in results:
  game_name = row[0]
  original_price = row[1]
  discount_price = row[2]
  print "game_name=%s, original_price=%s, discount_price=%s" % \
         (game_name, original_price, discount_price)
#For testing
checkDb()
```

It currently succeeds and gets 2,800 records in just a few(~15) seconds, including DB save. I am now adding in additional code to review if an entry exists, and only update if they exist.

I wrapped both parts into functions so I can easily test them out without writing duplicates.

Welcome any feedback. While this is working, I am not even sure how to begin refactoring it for redundancy sake.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some notes grouped by categories.

#### HTML Parsing

Instead of collecting names and amounts in separate lists, iterate over the elements with a `tab_row` class and collect the results into a single list of dictionaries.

You can get performance improvements by [switching to `lxml` from `html.parser`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use). Requires `lxml` to be installed.

You can use more concise [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of `find_all()`.

You can also use [`SoupStrainer` class](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) that would allow to improve on parsing speed by limiting what the parsing tree to the desired part only.

#### Working with the database

First of all, **do not use string formatting to pass your query parameters into the query**. You are not only exposing your code to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but also get potential issues with character escaping and type conversions. Use *parameterized queries* instead.

If you are gonna collect your data into the list of dictionaries, you may do your insert via `executemany()` which, aside from being more concise,
may provide a performance boost as well.

It is also a good idea to use multi-line strings for your database queries.

#### Code Style

There are multiple code style issues. The code is not [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)-complaint. Please analyze your code with `flake8`, `pylint` or other linters.

Also, don't repeat the database connection code, extract it into a separate function and reuse.

---

Here is the modified version of the code (renamed functions and logically separated into multiple functions):

```
import sys
import urllib2

import MySQLdb as mdb
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

import dbconfig as cfg


def db_connect():
    connection = mdb.connect(cfg.mysql['host'], cfg.mysql['user'], cfg.mysql['passwd'], cfg.mysql['db'])
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    
    connection.set_character_set('utf8')
    cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
    cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
    cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')

    return connection, cursor


def pull_games(page):
    parse_only = SoupStrainer(class_='tab_row')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)

    return [
        {
            'name': row.h4.get_text(),
            'price': row.select_one(".discount_original_price").get_text(),
            'discount': row.select_one('.discount_final_price').get_text()
        }
        for row in soup.select(".tab_row")
    ]


def insert_games(connection, cursor, data):
    query = """
        INSERT INTO 
          game_pricing
          (game_name, original_price, discount_price)
      VALUES
          (%(name)s, %(price)s, %(discount)s)
    """
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
    connection.commit()


def check_games(cursor):
    query = """
        SELECT 
            game_name, original_price, discount_price 
        FROM 
            game_pricing
    """
    cursor.execute(query)

    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for game_name, original_price, discount_price in result:
        print("game_name=%s, original_price=%s, discount_price=%s" % (game_name, original_price, discount_price))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')

    url = 'http://localhost'
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    games = pull_games(page)

    try:
        connection, cursor = db_connect()
        insert_games(connection, cursor, games)
    
        check_games(cursor)
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the feedback. I hated my formatting too, but I was making such good progress on the script I wanted to complete it prior to looking up best-practices. I will review the compliant document.

I have a question about the way your document ends - I've seen this on a lot of Py scripts. What is the `if __name__ ==` etc function doing it? It seems like it's just a way to specify 'This is what should be ran on open'?

Comment: @DNorthrup right, [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) would help to avoid the code to be executed on import, but also has an code organizational impact - note how we've put all the top-level code there into a single place. Thanks. Hope that was helpful.